# Filesystem Hierarchy Standard: Where should my package install files in Linux?

Tags: debian-packaging, fhs

I'm looking for help understanding the [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml), particularly as it applies to software I'm developing. There seem to be nuances that neither I nor my colleagues are aware of.

I'm especially confused about whether the executable binaries are considered "shareable" files and/or "locally installed software" and/or "add-on application software packages". I wouldn't expect those to be mutually exclusive, but the FHS gives different locations for each.

For background: The software is a partially-privileged system service, part of a suite of security software. It's not considered critical to the boot process. I'll be distributing the software as deb and rpm packages. It's commercial, closed-source software.

- /usr: "shareable, read-only data" [FHS 4.1], where "shareable" is "can be stored on one host and used on others" [FHS 2] Seems to fit, since AFAIK the binaries could be installed on one volume that's mounted to several hosts.
- /usr/local: "Locally installed software must be placed within /usr/local rather than /usr" Also seems to fit, since the binaries could be installed locally.
- /opt: "for the installation of add-on application software packages" [FHS 3.13] Since the software isn't part of a distro, presumably it would count as "add-on", and it's being distributed as a "package".

So which is right, and why? I'm hoping that when I understand that I'll be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: adding debian-packaging because those folk are likely to know the answer, and I'll be making Debian packages (among others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion:

- `/usr` - Leave it alone, IMO it's for the OS installation and the OS installation *only*.  Per [FHS 3.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04.html#purpose18):  "Large software packages must not use a direct subdirectory under the `/usr` hierarchy."  So you're sharing `/usr/bin` with the OS.
- `/usr/local` - Tends to be used by local admins, often to build software, so isn't really the safest place.  I like to think of `/usr/local` as the "local" playground for the system's admins - IMO it's *theirs* to put their "locally installed (and likely locally *built*) software" in.
- `/opt` - Designed for non-OS packages.  Avoiding collisions in `/opt` is easy if you have a distinctive name.  Per [FHS 3.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html):  "`/opt` is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages."  That seems to be exactly what you're delivering.  I suspect it wouldn't be hard to get a unique LANANA-registered name, giving you at least *some* degree of certainty that you won't have a collision.  I suspect the reason many organizations don't use `/opt` is that making your software self-contained - like being able to locate its shared objects - is a bit harder.

Given all that, IMO the best place is `/opt`.  You're less likely to have a name collision, and less likely for a local admin cleaning a botched build out of `/usr/local` accidentally nuking your installed software.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Henle. I received a flatpak, and I'll install it under `/opt`.